# I use JavaScript function to generate strong password with uppercases lowercases symbols and numbers but it get error of read only

Tags: javascript

The error: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '16' of string 'Wr9[85(W|V,s/BdL^'

but I use code to define it as writable check script below ,
I got this error when put code in zappier
The script:

```
function getRandomChar(str) {
  return str.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length));
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (currentIndex != 0) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
  }

  return array;
}

function generatePHelper(groups, length) {
  return function() {
    let pass = groups.map(getRandomChar).join('');
  
    const str = groups.join('');
  
    for (let i = pass.length; i <= length; i++) {
      pass += getRandomChar(str)
    }
    return shuffle(pass);
  };
}

const groups = [
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
  '1234567890',
  '!@#$%^&()_+~`|}{[]:;?><,./-='
];

const generateP = {};
Object.defineProperty(generateP, 'property1', {
writable: true,
  value: generatePHelper(groups, 16)
  
});
alert(generateP.property1())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on with that code, but the error message is very clear. You're attempting to do something like `var foo = "Wr9[85(W|V,s/BdL^"; foo[16] = "something";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `shuffle()` you get a string (read only type), but you use it as an array (changeable type). Try this (changed and added lines are marked with comments):

```js
function shuffle(str) { // changed 
  const array = [...str];  // added

  var currentIndex = array.length,  randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (currentIndex != 0) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]];
  }

  return array.join(''); // changed 
}
```